# Отслеживание оплаты google подписки

Tags: android, android-billing

Есть приложение со встроенной подпиской(3 дня триал, потом оплата)
Это приложение рекламируют 4 разных человека, у каждого есть своя уникальная ссылка(диплинк) который приводит человека в приложение и сохраняется там.
Вопрос: Как понять по какому диплинку прошла оплата, т.е человек не отменил подписку за время триального периода, а именно оплатил. Есть ли сервисы с подобной аналитикой или же как это можно реализовать?

Comment: В самом приложении вы можете лишь получить событие подписки. Событие оплаты в приложении получить невозможно. Может быть что-то такое есть в API PlayMarket, но лично я такого не помню. Т.е. копать надо в сторону собственного сервера с БД который принимает информацию от приложения (дип.линк+id подписки) и пытается её как-то сопоставить с тем, что можно получить с API гугла. Но не факт, что вы там найдёте необходимые методы.